# Does iOS BLE scanning require location services to be enabled?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, privacy

An app being used for COVID-19 exposure notifications is asking for access to location services. The developers claim that location services must be enabled for BLE to work in this context. I'm not an iOS developer, but I am having trouble finding if this is accurate or not. This app does not use the Apple API for exposure notification, but it does use the same methodology. To work, the app must be able to scan for other BLE devices at all times, and there is some older discussion I found that indicates that MIGHT be the reason for requiring location services permission.

Comment: On Android, BLE use triggers a location permission request. On iOS, Bluetooth has its own permission request, so the answer is "no", an app doesn't need location permission on iOS to uss BLE scanning (unless they are using iBeacons in which case you need location permission and not Bluetooth permission)

Comment: What if they were publicly advertising and looking for other devices with the same functionality? Like can you put an iOS phone into beacon mode?

Comment: A phone can be a beacon but only when the app is acting in the foreground. To advertise as a beacon you need Bluetooth permission. To discover beacons you need location permission